# Добавление связанных элементов

Tags: битрикс

Приветствую всех.
Столкнулся с очень непонятным поведением битриса при добавлении через апи товара и к нему торгового предложения.

Код следующий:

```
$intSKUIBlock = 3; // ID инфоблока предложений (должен быть торговым каталогом)
$arCatalog = CCatalog::GetByID($intSKUIBlock);
if (!$arCatalog)
    return;
    $intProductIBlock = $arCatalog['PRODUCT_IBLOCK_ID']; // ID инфоблока товаров

    $intSKUProperty = $arCatalog['SKU_PROPERTY_ID']; // ID свойства в инфоблоке предложений типа "Привязка к товарам (SKU)"

    $obElement = new CIBlockElement();
    // Сохраняем товар
    $arFields = array(
            'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'=>false,
            'NAME' => 'Товар',
            'IBLOCK_ID' => $intProductIBlock,
            'ACTIVE' => 'Y',
    );

    if($intProductID = $obElement->Add($arFields)){ echo 'ADD'; } else {echo $obElement->LAST_ERROR;}

    if ($intProductID){
        $arProp[$intSKUProperty] = $intProductID;
        $arFieldsNew = array(
                'NAME' => 'Торговое',
                'IBLOCK_ID' => $intSKUIBlock,
                'ACTIVE' => 'Y',
                'PROPERTY_VALUES' => $arProp
        );

        if($intOfferID = $obElement->Add($arFieldsNew)){
            echo 'ADD 2';
        } else {
            echo $obElement->LAST_ERROR;
        }; // ID торгового предложения

    }
```

На выходе получаем:
Первый товар создался
Вывод трех NULL
Второй создался.
И проблема как раз заключается именно в этих 3х NULL.
Если закомментировать у второго добавления 'PROPERTY_VALUES' => $arProp - все отрабатывается как надо, в варианте как в коде - выводятся NULL.
Вот с чем может быть проблема?
Проверил в веб-окружении и на полностью обновленном проекте - поведение одинаковое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что между двумя выведенными сообщениями срабатывает какой-то дополнительный вывод.
Необходимо локализировать место где выводятся сообщения:

1. Добавьте только sku к уже существующему товару(должны вывеститесь 3 null)
2. Добавьте sku (без `PROPERTY_VALUES`), а уже потом выставьте товар через `CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx`

Во втором случае скорее всего вы не увидите null. В таком случае вы нашли место где они выводятся - добавление элемента. Либо это происходит в самом методе (если правили ядро), либо в обработчиках события.

Можно вывести все обработчики событий:

```
print_r(GetModuleEvents("iblock", "OnIBlockElementAdd", true));
print_r(GetModuleEvents("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd", true));
print_r(GetModuleEvents("iblock", "OnStartIBlockElementAdd", true));
print_r(GetModuleEvents("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd", true));
print_r(GetModuleEvents("iblock", "OnIBlockElementSetPropertyValues", true));
print_r(GetModuleEvents("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementSetPropertyValues", true));
```

Обработчики содержат классы и методы (или функции). Стоит особенно обратить внимание на не битриксовые обработчики.

Если же во втором случае вывод null сохраниться то стоит смотреть на метод на более глубокие слои api (обращение к базе данных например)